# Some of the add to cart and product detail buttons do not work in Firefox

Tags: product-list

The last "learn more" and "add to cart" buttons do not work on the following page in Firefox: http://animalnecessity.com/all-natural-pet-care-supplement-products/ocuglo-rx-dog-eye-care.html. There are no javascript errors in console and I see no applicable PHP errors in logs. Any ideas?

Comment: Consider revising, adding more content to your post so that it may help others if the link stops working at some point in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the inline css: `"display:inline"` from the ul with products-grid class.

You cant have block elements inside inline elements.